# Connect Microsoft Graph in Azure DevOps pipelines with AzContext token

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to run `Connect-MgGraph` in my PowerShell script and I am getting following error:

`WARNING: Interactive authentication is not supported in this session, falling back to DeviceCode. Future versions will not automatically fallback to DeviceCode.`

But the pipeline is authenticated through `AzContext`. All previous PowerShell scripts are running successfully when I call `Connect-AzAccount` for example. So it should not ask for device code.

Here is my pipeline:

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Update App Registration'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: 'scripts/the_script.ps1'
    pwsh: true
```

and the script file:

```
Connect-MgGraph

$appDisplayName = "my-app"
$objectId = Get-MgApplication -Filter "displayName eq '$appDisplayName'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
```

How do I authenticate `Connect-MgGraph` using `AzContext`?

PS. I made sure my `azureSubscription` has `Application.ReadWrite.All` assigned.

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented fix for this [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/669).

First, you need to get a Microsoft Graph access token from `AzContext`, then set it to `Connect-MgGraph`.

So the solution would work like this, while keeping the pipeline task the same:

```yaml
$context = Get-AzContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphToken

$appDisplayName = "my-app"
$objectId = Get-MgApplication -Filter "displayName eq '$appDisplayName'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
```

PS: Remember that your service connection (azureSubscription value in this case) should have  at least `Application.Read.All` assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue, just one correction to Serhat post.

```
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken (ConvertTo-SecureString $graphToken -AsPlainText -Force)
```